# How to generate a name attribute for two-way binding using [(ngModel)] in a loop in angular 2?

Tags: html, angular

First of all, I don't understand why Angular 2 requires a name attribute if binding input using [(ngModel)]. Otherwise, I get this error:

```
    ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name
    attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 
    'standalone' in ngModelOptions.
```

It's normally not a problem, but how do I do it in a loop using *ngFor? Is index (like $index in angular 1) available?

Comment: can't you use the name of what you are iterating over ?

Comment: `*ngFor="let foo of bars; let i=index"` then you can use the `i` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get index this way and create input names distinctly with the `i` variable.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <input name="{{i}}"/>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks!. two minor fixes though: 1. use let instead of * for newer angular releases, 2. user {{i}} instead of i.

Answer (score 2):

To address the question:

> *First of all, I don't understand why Angular 2 requires a name attribute if binding input using [(ngModel)]*

Some info gathered from here: [**Official docs for Forms**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html):

First off, we just need this in forms. Name attribute is a requirement when using `[(ngModel)]` in combination with a form.

Internally, Angular creates `FormControl` instances and registers them with your [**`NgForm`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html) directive.  Angular automatically attaches the `NgForm` directive to the `<form>`-tag. The `NgForm` directive supplements the form element with additional features. It holds the controls you created for the elements with `ngModel` directive and `name` attribute, and monitors their properties, including their validity.

Each `FormControl` is registered under the name you assigned to the `name` attribute. Therefore this means that each name needs to be unique, if not, then each field with the same name would be evaluated as one and the same.

Normally, outside a loop, it would be enough to do:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="item.name" name="name">
```

But inside the loop this would not be sufficient, as all fields would have the same `name`-attribute.

So like suggested by Eduardo, when you loop, this can be solved very easily by using the index:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <input [(ngModel)]="item.name" name="name{{i}}"/>
</ul>
```